# using POST method in gridview pjax search in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have a gridview in yii2 advanced app and i want to use `post` method for searching data for that grid,which is not a problem and i can do that using below code

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'grid', 'timeout' => false ,'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST'] ]); ?>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

But now the problem is how should i get the data send using `post` in `Search` model of that table.

Right now what i did was to check the $_POST and assign that to `$params` in the code but i want to know is there any better way to do that than this below code

```
public function search($params)
{
    if(isset ($_POST)){
        $params = $_POST;
    }

    $query = Event::find()-> where(['organiser_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

    $this->load($params);

    $query->joinWith(['interest']);

    if (!$this->validate()) {

        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'organiser_id' => $this->organiser_id,
        'is_active' => $this->is_active,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: did you get  this to work? i can't get mine too. can share your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function search($params)
{
    if(isset ($_POST['SearchModel'])){
        $this->load = \Yii::$app->request->post();
    }

   //searching code here
}
```

in your Index Action where Search is implemented use As:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new SearchModel(); //Your Search Model Class
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($post);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

In Search Model Class::

```
public function search($params)
    {


        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);
}
```

Comment: i dont get that how this will work but i will try and get back to you because even after adding your code `$params` value will still be empty right....